# Finding the summation of the series.

Tags: number-theory, summation

Is there any formula to find out the summation of the series.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \lfloor \frac{n}{i} \rfloor$$
Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Doubt you'll get a simple closed form. Check https://oeis.org/A006218